# How to convert PDF generated from reportlab in Python to HTML

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, reportlab, pdf-to-html

I have finished generating a **PDF** with tables, headers and **clickable TOC** styled nicely. Now I would like to have an `HTML version`. Is it possible to use the same `ReportLab` to just easily generate the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the opposite is a lot easier (HTML -> PDF). ReportLab commercial has an option for this, as does [xhtml2pdf](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf). For PDF -> HTML, you can try [PDF2Tree](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotree/).

The direct answer to this question is: No. ReportLab does not have an easy way to do this. At least not according to their [documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf).